# Json Schema - multiple if-then clauses inside an array

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I've been working around this problem for a time, but I don't get a solution.

Json files follow an structure similar to this one:

```
[
  {
    "type": "label",
    "element": "text_lbl_1",
    "value": "Some text here"
  },
  {
    "type": "label",
    "element": "text_lbl_2",
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "type": "image",
    "element": "im_url_1",
    "value": "https://example.com/image/kartofen.png"
  }
]
```

So its a list of objects, where I would like to validate that `type` and `value` type are aligned: label should have an string, image should have an url.

My proposed schema is:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
      "type",
      "element",
      "value"
    ],
    "allOf": [
      {
        "if": {
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "const": "label"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "type"
          ],
          "then": {
            "properties": {
              "value": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "if": {
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "const": "image"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "type"
          ],
          "then": {
            "properties": {
              "value": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "uri"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But it should validate wrong with previous json, as label value could not be a number. You could check it [here](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/bXCHY21q)

I will validate this against python's jsonschema implementation, so I am working with draft 7.

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Your schema is working fine. You just had your `then` keywords as children of `if` but they should be on the same level:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": [ "type", "element", "value" ],
    "allOf": [
      {
        "if": {
          "properties": {
            "type": { "const": "label" }
          },
          "required": [ "type" ]
        },
        "then": {
          "properties": {
            "value": { "type": "string" }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "if": {
          "properties": {
            "type": { "const": "image" }
          },
          "required": [ "type" ]
        },
        "then": {
          "properties": {
            "value": {
              "type": "string",
              "format": "uri"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image: Validation error in JSONBuddy]